# Angular and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

Is there any official way to get them merge together or should I just pass and work with jQuery-mobile alone.

Because I tried something as simple as making a `ul`-list and the `<li>` just get crushed one inside the other.

Comment: They should be fine...remove your angular reference, is it still happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter?
It merges the two frameworks and works pretty well actually.